# Sometimes all of my directories are locked and I have to restart to fix it, I wonder why?

Tags: 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my HP Pavilion-14 ex024tc laptop. It works well, but sometimes it would lock all of my folders while there shows a small lock icon along with the folder's icon.

When that happens, I can only visit my files in read-only mode, It really matters. So I have to reboot my laptop and I'll get a info told me that there is a mount error and I need to press F to fix it. It always work so I can use my computer normally after that.

I want to know why this matter happens and I want to fix it. Any one have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you use `Shutdown` to turn off your computer, or `Suspend` (=hibernate)?

Comment: @Hannu I use shutdown

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use "mount" command in console and look for / if it is mounted as ro (readonly) or rw (readwrite).

If it is mounted as ro, please check /var/log/syslog (you can use tail or less) for disk errors. Normally root partition is remounted on errors as read only - so that probably means your hard drive has failure or your filesystem is corrupted.

I recommend you to run this command as root (when filesystem is read-write) "touch /forcefsck" and reboot your system. This will force file system check and might solve your issue.